# Case When Statement First Character Match Letter Range

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a problem to separate the name into a category. I have a big list of names and want separate them in a Category column based on the first character match with letter range (e.g. [A-C], [D-E]...). Here is an example:

```
SELECT RecID, Name
, CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'A' THEN
        'Cat1'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'B' THEN
        'Cat1'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'C' THEN
        'Cat1'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'D' THEN
        'Cat2'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'E' THEN
        'Cat2'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'F' THEN
        'Cat3'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'G' THEN
        'Cat3'
    ELSE
        'Cat999'
   END AS Category 
FROM Table1
```

I could use WHEN statement for every letters and numbers, but that would be too much.  Is there a way I can do like this below? regex maybe?

```
SELECT RecID, Name
, CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'A-C' THEN
        'Cat1'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'D-E' THEN
        'Cat2'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) = 'F-G' THEN
        'Cat3'
    ELSE
        'Cat999'
   END AS Category 
FROM Table1
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT RecID, Name
, CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) Like '[A-C]' THEN
        'Cat1'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) Like '[D-E]' THEN
        'Cat2'
    WHEN LEFT(Name, 1) Like '[F-G]' THEN
        'Cat3'
    ELSE
        'Cat999'
   END AS Category
```

Comment: As mentioned by Used_By_Already (cool name), the between works as well

Comment: That works perfect!  I didn't know I can use LIKE '[]' as the letter range.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use between e.g

```
  When left(name,1) between 'A' and 'C'
```

Comment: Thank you this solution too.